# How to make the following program of job indexing efficient?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a list of jobs from which i have to take the jobs which are done and put them in a index. The list of jobs will keep updating in a particular time gap.

I created a program with the following parameters and the algorithm goes like this.
I have parameters all_jobs,jobs_done,jobs_done_temp,jobs_tobe_indexed set to empty lists.

```
while(True):
    all_jobs = list(service.jobs)       
    for job in all_jobs:
        if job["isDone"] == '1':
            jobs_done.append(job.sid)

    jobs_tobe_indexed = list(set(jobs_done) - set(jobs_done_temp)) #Gets the jobs which are done and not yet indexed.
    jobs_done_temp = jobs_done[:] #Copying the jobs_done to the jobs which are indexed so that the set operation above will give jobs which are not done in the next iteration

    for job in jobs_tobe_indexed:
        #Index all the jobs
```

I have to run this script continuously. The all_jobs will keep updating will remove the old jobs which it has automatically.

The problem here is that, the values in jobs_done and jobs_done_temp will keep on increasing and will create memory overflow in future.***New jobs will keep on coming and the list all_jobs will contain new jobs and some old jobs.We should get the new done jobs from them and index it. Jobs which are indexed once shouldn't be indexed again.***

Can anyone find a better tell me a better way of doing this with proper memory management.

Comment: This is what a database is for... be that a text file, SQLite, Oracle or a Hadoop cluster (scale as appropriate). Alternatively, if you're only storing the session ID then reconsider whether or not you need to store anything at all and consider the length of time such storage is actually required.

Comment: `jobs_done` never gets removed from and is thus bound to grow indefinitely. Can you elaborate on the context, i.e. what you are actually trying to achieve? There is simply not enough information to suggest an improvement.

Comment: The main thing is that , jobs which are done and indexed shouldn't be indexed again. New jobs will keep on coming. I should find the once which are done and not indexed; and put them into the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_done(job):
    return job['isDone'] == '1'

done_jobs = filter(is_done, jobs)
```

Would this accomplish what you're asking?